# Tree traversal, passed variable is reset to 0 when exiting the final recursion (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

Can someone explain to me why given this code to traverse a binary tree:

```
var sumOfLeftLeaves = function(root) {
    let sum = 0;
    traverse(root, sum);
    return sum;
};


function traverse(root, sum) {

    const left = root.left;
    const right = root.right;


    if (left) {
        sum += left.val;
        traverse(left, sum);
    }

    if (right) {
        traverse(right, sum);
    }

}
```

the sum that has been correctly calculated during the traversal of the tree, is reset to 0 after exiting the last recursive stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sumOfLeftLeaves = function(root) {
    let sum = 0;
    return traverse(root, sum);
};


function traverse(root, sum) {

    const left = root.left;
    const right = root.right;

    sum += root.val
    if (left) {
        sum += traverse(left, sum);
    }

    if (right) {
        sum += traverse(right, sum);
    }
    return sum

}
```

`sum` is an immutable value. This means that each time you pass it as an argument to a function call a new copy is made. Therefore, the additions you make further down the recursive stack are not reflected on the `sum` variable in the stack frames above.

*To further elaborate*, `sum` is an integer, `Number` in JS terms. It is a value type, meaning that on each assignment, it is passed by value, copied over. In other words, the JS runtime, creates a new place on the stack and stores the value that was assigned in the new place. Any mutation/modification you do on the value type, is not reflected on original variable.

This approach solves the problem.

Another approach would be to remove `sum` as a parameter and only return the sum of the node values as follows:

```js
var sumOfLeftLeaves = function(root) {
    return traverse(root);
};


function traverse(root) {
    if (root == null) return 0

    return root.val + traverse(root.left) + traverse(root.right);
}
```

For completeness sake, a third approach would be to make `sum` a mutable variable, like a js object type or an array. While the object's or array's structure itself is passed by value, their contents can be changed and those changes will be reflected in the original variable. Let's say you pass `sum` as an array of one element, `const sum = [0]`. Whenever you add something to it, `sum[0] += node.val`, the value of the element at index zero of `sum` changes and is also visible to functions further above the call stack.

Comment: So why sum is immutable? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the answer as it wouldn't fit in comments.

Comment: I have added some more comments at the end that may help if you want to further test and explore.

Comment: I got really confused as I usually don't use javascript but typescript. Now I'm not sure actually if I ever used numbers in recursive functions and modified the original number or it was an object. I am not sure whether there's a difference between the 2 languages in that regard, or I am just dumb. Probably the latter

Comment: there is no difference in this regard between js and ts. you have probably worked with objects, which are mutable. dw.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning `sum` from `traverse`, and not reassigning it in `sumOfLeftLeaves` either. You probably want something more like this:

```
var sumOfLeftLeaves = function(root) {
    return traverse(root, 0);
};


function traverse(root, sum) {
    const left = root.left;
    const right = root.right;

    if (left) {
        sum += left.val;
        return traverse(left, sum);
    }

    if (right) {
        return traverse(right, sum);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single function which returns either the value plus left and right side or zero.

```
const
    sumOfTree = node => node
        ? value + sumOfTree(node.left) + sumOfTree(node.right)
        : 0;
```

Another solution could be to use a traverse function which takes a node and a function with a closure over an object for the value.

```
const
    traverse = (node, fn) => {
        if (!node) return;
        fn(node);
        traverse(node.left, fn);
        traverse(node.right, fn);
    },
    sumOfTree = result => node => result.sum += node.value;

// call
const
    result = { sum: 0 },
    getSum = sumOfTree(result);

traverse(tree, getSum);
console.log(result.sum);
```

Comment: I always learn from your js implementations.